# Android : Dedicated Memory Allocation For Application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, kernel

[Asking the same question but not for iPhone but for Android platform]

I want to allocate small part of memory specially to my application to use. The purpose of doing that is another application running on my Android phone will not affect my application in any case.

Is it possible or not ? If yes then How ?

Any link or any help would help me...

Thanks In Advance

Comment: defeats the whole idea of good 'citizen' mobile app programming.

Comment: maybe the C function malloc can do it (dont know), but you cannot force NSStrings, or any NSObject from the framework to use that memory

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible in practice. Theoretically, an app that included a kernel extension could have the extension allocate some wired memory and pass a reference to that memory up to the application process. This isn't possible within the restrictions imposed on iOS apps - the kernel interface isn't available.

Comment: Thanks Graham for quick response...Is it possible to write a seperate(our own customized) kernal for that ? Is apple allow this ? because I really need this functionality.

Comment: No. You can't distribute the kernel with your app, for the same reason you can't distribute a kernel extension.