# Dedicated memory allocation for mobile application

Tags: android, android-layout, kernel-module, kernel

This question is for Android/any smart phone OS.

I want to allocate small part of memory specially to my application to use. The purpose of doing that is another application running on my phone will not affect my application in any case.

Is it possible or not ? If yes then How ?

Any link or any help would help me...

Thanks In Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Dedicated Memory Allocation For Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439135/android-dedicated-memory-allocation-for-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a custom kernel/modified OS to run on your own device then yes, you can do it. For this, you'll have to go deep into OS architecture, memory management etc

If you plan to do this on commercial devices that are sold to customers (Android, ios etc), then no OS will provide you API's to do this.

Comment: Anup...you are saying like if we will modify the OS then we can do this right ? and We can also achieve the same with Android OS...is it correct ?

Comment: You can take the android source code and create a custom version of it to do this. But that'll only be available on your modified OS, not on the Android that consumers use.

Comment: Can I do formate(uninstall) android OS from my galaxy and install customized OS in it ? How can I  ? Please suggest

Comment: No. You'' have to root your device, create a custom rom and install it on your device. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232620/getting-started-with-creating-custom-roms

Answer (score 1):

All Memory Management handling is done for the applications by the OS (Linux for Android). So whenever an application is launched, Dalvik VM interacts with the Linux kernel and gets the momory allocated for it. While your application is in the Foreground, it has all allocated memory available, but ones it is pushed to the background, this memory might be taken away from it.

So you **cannot** allocate a small part of memory to yourself permanently. This is already done for you by the OS (part of internal storage). But you cannot occupy a small part of the RAM and hence deny space to other applications.